# Different surnames on passports of dual citizen

Tags: passports, germany, dual-nationality, south-africa

I am a 17-year-old and am traveling to Germany later this year from South Africa. My German passport and my South African passport have different surnames. Will there be any problems in my travels and, if so, how do I overcome this issue?

Comment: Do you have any other legal document(s) that explain (such as your German passport has your mother's surname, the SA has your father's or a stepfather, etc.)?

Comment: Are you traveling with or without one or more parents?

Comment: Are you planning to use both passports (for example one when entering Germany and second where entering South Africa) Which one is / will be on the plane ticket?

Comment: Only in the very rare case where a sovereignty event arises in a 3rd country.

Comment: @GayotFow what is a "sovereignty event"?

Comment: @phoog where the two countries have to sort out sovereignty with a 3rd country.

Comment: @GayotFow what does "sort out sovereignty" mean?  Can you give an example?  Are you referring to the question of whether a third country will grant the right of consular representation with respect to one or the other of the person's countries of citizenship?  Or is it something else, like whether one country recognizes the other as a sovereign state?

Comment: @phoog more like the former, like when we evacuate people in a disaster or the person dies or robs a bank etc